# fiddler input to multiple dictionary objects

Tags: asp.net-web-api, fiddler

I have a WebAPI which take two dictionary obects as inputs
I want to test this using fildder:
I tried many ways.ut all these combinations throws the error:"Can't bind multiple parameters to the request's content
Note: For one dictionary object, the input { "-x": "temp "} just works fine without any problem but multiple dictionary object ,I don't know how to pass values from fiddler.

Comment: Do you have a client that sends such an object? The simplest thing to do would be to just capture its output with Fiddler; you can then drag/drop that request to Fiddler's Composer tab and edit as desired.

Answer (score 0):

I found a work around.I kept the two dictionary to a list since both the dictionary have same signature.